# How to update after successful build-gnuradio?

Tags: git, build, installation, gnuradio

After successfully building gnuradio using the build-gnuradio script ([Using the build-gnuradio script](http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/InstallingGR#Using-the-build-gnuradio-script)), is there a way to update and build everything new without starting over?

E.g., some way to do all the right git pulls and build/install everything based on the changed files/dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git pull
rm -Rf build
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ../
make
sudo make install
```

This worked for me when updating to 3.6.2

Answer (score 2):

I've never used build-gnuradio but it looks like it just does a git clone from the repository.  If you go into the gnuradio directory you should just be able to do

```
git pull
cd build
make
sudo make install
```

or something along those lines.

Comment: I'd upvote this if I had enough rep.  Besides gnuradio there are several other subdirs with .git subdirs.  All the Makefiles seem to be in the top subdir of each subsystem so there don't seem to be build dirs.

Comment: My guess would be that for those you just do the 'make' and 'sudo make install' in the top subdir.

Comment: That's what I've done and it seems to work.  I haven't actually done a diff between the "git pull" process and a clean build.  Would be interesting to see if there is a difference, or if any differences are significant.  Thanks!